# Smart sentence segmentation not splitting on abbreviations

Tags: python, nlp, preprocessing, nltk, spacy

Sentencer from SpaCy and NLTK does not catch the fact that typical abbreviations (e.g. `Mio.` for `Million` in German) and the resulting sentence split is not correct. I understand that sentencers are supposed to be simple and quick but I am wondering if there is a better one that takes into account something more than uppercased words and punctuation? Alternatively, how to make SpaCy / NLTK / ... sentencer work for such sentences?

I am interested primarily with sentencers with Python API.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Neural tools trained on [Universal Dependencies corpora](https://universaldependencies.org/) use learned models for tokenization and sentence-spliting. Two I know of are:

- [UDPipe](https://ufal.mff.cuni.cz/udpipe/1/users-manual) – developed at Charles University in Prague. Gets very good results (at least for parsing), but has a little unintuitive API.
- [Stanza](https://stanfordnlp.github.io/stanza/index.html) – developed at Stanford University. The API is quite similar to Spacy.

However, they are quite slow compared to regex-based sentence-spliting.

Comment: Thank you for the references. The speed is not an issue.